# Can I separate two fill legends in ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set that I'm trying to plot using ggplot2 in R where I want to use the fill aesthetic twice in two different ways (yes/no for one variable, scaled for another).

An example data set:

```
df <- data.frame(Season = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), times = 3), 
                 Scenario = rep(c('S1', 'S2', 'S3'), each = 4),
                 meanA = rep(1, 12), meanB = rep(2,12))
```

I want points for `meanA` to be filled and points for `meanB` to be empty. I want color to scale with `Scenario` for both sets and I also want the fill for `meanA` to scale with `Scenario`. I've managed to get the graph the way I want it to look:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Season, meanA)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Scenario, fill = Scenario), shape = 24,
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = meanB, color = Scenario), fill = NA, shape = 25,
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)) +
  ylim(0,3)
```

[image: Example Plot]

The issue I'm running into, though, is that I want two legends: one with the two shapes (filled up triangle, empty down triangle) and one with the scaled fill/color by scenario. The plot as of right now only has one legend with filled and unfilled symbols overlapping. How can I get the legends to look the way I want?

Answer (score 1):

With a little reshaping and the `guides` function, you can get there:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(Season = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), times = 3), 
                 Scenario = rep(c('S1', 'S2', 'S3'), each = 4),
                 meanA = rep(1, 12), meanB = rep(2,12))

df2 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    meanA:meanB, names_to = "var", values_to = "val"
  )

ggplot(df2, aes(Season, val, shape = var, color = Scenario)) +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(var == "meanA"), aes(fill = Scenario),
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)) +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(var == "meanB"), aes(fill = NULL),
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(24, 25)) +
  guides(
    shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("#F8766D", NA)))
  ) +
  ylim(0,3)
```